# Run OpenVPN server on alias IP

Tags: openvpn, ip-aliasing

I want to configure OpenVPN server that works on alias IP. I changed the client config to have alias IP as remote and added "local 188.xx.xx.55" in OpenVPN config which is our alias IP. Also set "netd_interface=188.xx.xx.55" which is again alias ip. When the VPN connects and I check my public IP it displays xx.xx.207.4 which is the original IP not the alias IP we want it to work on.
Can anyone please guide me how to make it work either with NATD or PF? If you want any more info just ask in comments and I'll post it.

Correction:
"00050 divert 8668 ip4 from any to any via bge0" this ipfw rule is configured which might be causing the issue. Please look at my IP configuration below.

> bge0: flags=8843 metric 0 mtu 1500
>       options=c019b
>       ether xx:xx:97:xx:e5:xx
>       hwaddr xx:xx:97:xx:e5:xx
>       **inet xx.xx.207.4** netmask 0xffffffc0 broadcast xx.xx.xx.63 
>       **inet 188.xx.xx.55** netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 188.xx.xx.55 
>       nd6 options=29
>       media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT )
>       status: active
>
> **openvpn.conf:**
>   local 188.xx.xx.55
>   port 50983
>   push "route 188.xx.xx.55 255.255.255.255"
>   askpass
>   proto udp
>   dev tun
>   ca ca.crt
>   cert server.crt
>   key server.key
>   dh dh.pem
>   server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>   keepalive 10 120
>   comp-lzo
>   persist-key
>   persist-tun
>   verify-client-cert none
>   plugin /usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins/open$
>   status openvpn-status.log
>   verb 3
>   push "redirect-gateway autolocal def1"
>   push "redirect-gateway local def1"
>   push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
>   push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
>
> **rc.conf:**
>   firewall_enable="YES"
>   firewall_type="open"
>   hostname="example.com"
>   ifconfig_bge0="inet xx.xx.207.4 netmask 255.255.255.197
>   defaultrouter="xx.xx.207.1"
>   ifconfig_bge0_alias0="inet 188.xx.xx.55  n$
>   gateway_enable="YES"
>   natd_enable="YES"
>   natd_flags="-alias_address 188.xx.xx.55"
>   openvpn_enable="YES"
>   openvpn_if="tun"
>
> **ipfw rules:**
>   00050 divert 8668 ip4 from any to any via bge0
>   00100 allow ip from any to any via lo0
>   00200 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
>   00300 deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
>   00400 deny ip from any to ::1
>   00500 deny ip from ::1 to any
>   00600 allow ipv6-icmp from :: to ff02::/16
>   00700 allow ipv6-icmp from fe80::/10 to fe$
>   00800 allow ipv6-icmp from fe80::/10 to ff$ 
>   00900 allow ipv6-icmp from any to any ip6 $
>   01000 allow ipv6-icmp from any to any ip6 $
>   65000 allow ip from any to any
>   65535 deny ip from any to any

Comment: Please try to use proper capitalisation and the formatting options to make your posts more readable.  - *"When I check my public IP it displays xx.xx.207.4 which is the original ip not the alias ip"* my first guess is that your VPN server is correctly configured to accept incoming traffic on the new IP-address but that you still need to adjust the rules in your firewall configuration to NAT/MASQUERADE with the new IP-address rather than primary IP-address for your internet network interface.

Comment: Okay first of all i am new to all of this so bare with me. currently natd is configured. and in my rc.conf i have natd_interface="188.xx.xx.55" option which is the alias ip
second i added push "route 188.xx.xx.55 255.255.255.255" in the openvpn.conf and "pull" on the client ovpn file.
now how do i configure firewall? i am using ipfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually using `natd` for NAT, as this is FreeBSD and your `ipfw` rule uses divert socket to forward traffic to it. Look at your `/etc/rc.conf` for `nat_interface` option, it is currently set to your output interface name.

By default, with this configuration, `natd` will use primary address of the specified interface as a masquerade.
To change this behavior, you have to remove `natd_interface` stanza altogether from `rc.conf`, and change your `natd_flags` line there (or create one if it doesn't exist) to include this:

`natd_flags="-alias_address A.B.C.D"`

Where A.B.C.D should be your desired masquerade IP address.

Comment: I tried what you said and it also seems logical but sadly it didn't work. here are my config files in the edits maybe if you can spot a mistake. Sorry for my poor editing skills.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Have you restarted `natd` after making these changes?

Comment: yes i did restarted both networking and openvpn service.
can you check my config?

Comment: You have to restart `natd`. You can do this by issuing `/etc/rc.d/natd restart`.

Comment: i did restart a couple of times mate.

Comment: So what kind of behavior you're seeing then?

Comment: axactly the same. i am connecting with ovpn file which contains 188.xx.xx.55( alias ip) and after connecting if i check my ip online it says xx.xx.207.4(primary ip).

Comment: Can you check with `ps auxwww` what arguments your `natd` instance is started with?

Comment: strange but it started with `/sbin/natd -dynamic -m -n bge0` that line is commented out in `rc.conf`

Answer (score -1):

finally it worked. I restarted natif and routing too along with natd. +1 for @Peter Zhabin. thank you brother so much. you finally saved me. Sadly my repution is not grater then 15 as i am new here too so i can't up vote your answer but your solution does work.

Comment: You certainly _can_ accept it though! And that would also give you 2 repuation points. You can get 2 more (returned to you) by putting this "answer" into a comment, and then deleting this.